A subset is large if and only if it contains all generic points
This is from "Groups and fields definable in o-minimal structures" by A. Pillay. In the paper, the author assumes that the structure we are working with is sufficiently saturated, but claims that the results remain true when working in non-saturated structures. I'm having some trouble proving that one particular lemma still holds when we are working with a non-saturated structure.
The lemma(Lemma 1.12 in the paper) is the following:

Let $\mathcal M$ be o-minimal and $Y\subseteq X$ be $A$-definable sets. Then $Y$ is large in $X$ if and only if $Y$ contains all generics of $X$ over $A$.

This is clearly true if $\cal M$ is sufficiently saturated, but I'm having some trouble proving the general case.
For instance, if $Y$ is large in $X$, then given any generic $x$ of $X$ over $A$, we have that $x \in Y$  (since otherwise we would get that $\dim(X\setminus Y) = \dim(X)$).
The other implication is the one I'm having trouble with:
Assume that  $Y$ contains all generic points of $X$ over $A$, and for the sake of contradiction, assume that $\dim(X\setminus Y) = n$, where $n = \dim(X)$. Then there exists $w \in (X\setminus Y)(\mathbb{M}) = X(\mathbb{M})\setminus Y(\mathbb{M})$ such that $\dim(w/A) = n$. As this proposition is true when the structure is sufficiently saturated, this means that there exists a generic of $X(\mathbb M)$ over $A$ that is not in $Y(\mathbb M)$. This is where I'm stuck. How do we conclude that there exists a generic of $X$ which is not on $Y$ from this?

The definitions I'm using are the following:

Let $\cal M$ be o-minimal. Let $\bar a \in M^n$ and $A\subseteq M$. We define $\dim(\bar a /A)$ to be the least cardinality of a subtuple $\bar a'\subseteq \bar a$ such that $\bar a \subseteq acl(A\cup \bar a')$.


For an o-minimal structure $\cal M$, given an $A$-definable set $X\subseteq M^n$, we define $$\dim(X) = \max \{\dim(x/A) : x \in X(\mathbb M)\}$$ Where $\mathcal{M}\preceq \mathbb M$ is a sufficnelty saturated elementary extension of $\mathcal M$. We say that $x \in X$ is generic over $A$ if $\dim(x/A) = \dim(X)$. When $\mathcal M$ is itself sufficiently saturated, we may take $\mathbb{M} = \mathcal M$.


Given two definable sets $Y\subseteq X$ we say that $Y$ is large in $X$ if $\dim(X\setminus Y) \le \dim (X)$.


Please start with some context. You want to attract people who can help you, and discourage people who can't, and making people make inferences about the context wastes their time.

Thanks. I've added some additional context @ThomasAndrews

This is false in general. For example, consider $M = \overline{\mathbb{Q}}\cap \mathbb{R}$, the ordered field of real algebraic numbers. This is a real closed field, hence o-minimal. By quantifier elimination for $\mathsf{RCF}$, $M\preceq \mathbb{R}$. Note that in $\mathbb{R}$, $\DeclareMathOperator{\acl}{acl}\acl(\varnothing) = M$.
We have $\dim(M) = 1$, since if $r\in \mathbb{R}$ is transcendental (i.e., not in $M$), then $r$ is not in $\acl(\varnothing)$. But for all $a\in M$, $a\in \acl(\varnothing)$, so $\dim(a/\varnothing) = 0$. In other words, $M$ contains no generics over $\varnothing$. It follows that $\varnothing\subseteq M$ contains all generics of $M$ over $\varnothing$. But $\varnothing$ is certainly not large in $M$, since $\dim(M\setminus \varnothing) = \dim(M)$.
Ok, so when Pillay wrote "all our results hold for arbitrary $M$", this is a bit misleading. I think what he meant is that the main results, i.e., the characterizations of groups and fields definable in o-minimal structures, hold for arbitrary $M$ (since they are invariant under taking elementary extendsions and elementary substructures). The proofs themselves, i.e. the supporting Lemmas, don't go through in arbitrary models.

Thank you. No wonder I couldn't prove it
